# Check if tableVIew is at the tableViewFooter

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a scrollView with several tableViews. I've created a tableViewFooter for each tableView. I want to perform a action is a specific tableView with the tag 102 is at the bottom/is at the tableViewFooter?

Here is a specific tableView which i would like to check:

```
    recentTableView = UITableView()
    recentTableView.tag = 101
    recentTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    recentTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, wBounds, hBounds)
    recentTableView.dataSource = self
    recentTableView.delegate = self
    recentTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    recentTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NewsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    recentTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f6f7f9")
    recentTableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    recentTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.scrollView.addSubview(recentTableView)
    self.scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(recentTableView)



    recentFooter.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)
    recentFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f6f7f9")
    var recentInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    recentInd.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-5, 20-5, 10.0, 10.0);
    recentInd.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
    recentInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
        UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    recentInd.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    recentFooter.addSubview(recentInd)
    recentInd.startAnimating()
    self.recentTableView.tableFooterView = self.recentFooter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)` method of `UITableViewDelegate`.

Or you can make use of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods on `UITableView` and check if it reaches until `tableViewFooter` in `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Something like that should work for you:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.tag == xxx) { //detect which tableView scrolled
         CGFloat footerViewY = {calculate the Y position of your footer view}
         //don't copy&paste the line below, you should change that line according to your needs
         if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= footerViewY) {
         //do something
         }
    }
}
```

If all those seem too complicated, maybe you can try to make a base UIView class for your footer views (i.e: XXBaseFooterView) and override drawRect method of base class, when drawRect is called it means it is visible. But I guess that way is very hacky and not reliable.

Comment: addition to my answer: I think you should calculate the frame of your tableFooterView in scrollViewDidScroll and check if it reaches there. willDisplayFooterView method works for section footer views but if possible maybe you can make it a section footer view.

Comment: so in scrollViewDidScroll i can do `if scrollView.tag == 101`? will it trigger the tableView